# How to make 'non-git' aliases permanent on git bash

Tags: git, alias

I'm scratching my head as to how to make my non-git aliases permanent. I know that, in order to make my git aliases permanent, I simply have to add them to '.gitconfig', e.g.:

```
[alias]
  st = status
  ci = commit
  br = branch
```

However, what about non-git.. e.g.

```
alias codePath='cd /c/code/pathToMyProject'
```

I have a number of conveniences like this one, which die with the terminal (sadly).

I'm running git bash on windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit a file `.bashrc` in your home directory.  Interactive shells run the commands in that when they start.

Comment: Great stuff - '.bashrc' didn't exist, but I added it with my aliases and away I went. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Set command line interface (CLI) alias

#### TEMPRARY Aliases

Terminal

```
alias p="pwd"
```

CMD /   webstorm

```
doskey websync=php bin/console assets:install web --symlink
```

//  no quotes ""

#### PERMANENT Aliases for

Terminal

step 1.

edit    C:\Users\seetpalsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\etc\bash.bashrc

put this at end of this file

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

alias websync="C:/xampp/php/php.exe bin/console assets:install web --symlink"

alias schema-up="C:/xampp/php/php.exe bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

CMD /   webstorm

step 1.

create a file with extension .cmd / .bat

e.g.    doskey.cmd

put this code in this .cmd/.bat file

```
doskey websync=C:\xampp\php\php.exe bin\console assets:install web --symlink

doskey schema-up=C:\xampp\php\php.exe bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

step 2.

create a link to CMD  something like this

```
cmd.exe /K E:\2015/doskey.cmd
```

required this is link to your file of alias list

```
/K E:\2015/doskey.cmd
```